# Serial Port or Network Keyboard Wedge (send keyboard strokes)

Tags: node.js

Reading and writing data to and from networks and serial ports are an easy thing for NodeJS, but what about sending the data as key strokes to to an application window like an iSeries Access terminal session in Windows?

Ideally NodeJS would handle all the receiving of data and send it to input focus of the active application window.

```
var com = require("serialport");

var serialPort = new com.SerialPort("COM1", {
    baudrate: 9600   
  });

serialPort.on('open',function() {
  console.log('Port open');
});

serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
  var data_to_send = data.toString();
  send_to_active_windows_input_focus(the_data_to_send+"\r"); <-- A keyboard wedge function 
});
```

Any ideas?

This would be NodeJS on a Windows 7 machine.